# Changing docker image download location on "play-with-docker"

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying create a container for Jupyter datascience notebook on "Play-with-docker" using following links:
https://labs.play-with-docker.com/
https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook`

"Play with docker" has its own limitation as its a free source to play around and test docker in a browser.
By default it downloads an image at "/var/lib/docker" and there's only 4.7 GB of space available in /var/ location. With this as default, I am unable to download the image as it throws error of `disk quota exceeded`
Although "/etc" seems to have 64GB.

Tried changing the graph directory but unable to do so as this platform doesn't allow to restart the docker service or daemon.

Is there any way we can change download location on "Play-with-docker" so it allows downloading bigger images?

Comment: [this page](https://microbadger.com/images/jupyter/datascience-notebook) taken from the link you provided shows the image is only 2GB big. If you want to move the `/var/lib/docker` installation directory on your computer you could always use a symlink to another location.

Comment: Not exactly sure what goes behind the scene while downloading an image, but despite being 2GB of image, it throws the `disk quota exceeded` error. Maybe downloaded layer or extraction process takes up all the space temporarily. Will look into how symlink works.

Comment: @Aserre: Symlink is just a pointer to a different location. It is still taking up space at its original location.

Comment: If you you do `ln -s /path/to/folder /var/lib/docker`, you will transform the docker directory into a symlink. It will mean that every file you download to `/var/lib/docker` will in fact be moved to your other folder. Read the man page for more details.

Comment: Tried `ln -s /etc/image_docker/ /var/lib/docker` and now its taking space at both the places. Can you try the solution at your end and help with the reproducible code. I am new to this and might have taken a wrong attempt to this.